# jqXHR object removes itself and container from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am storing jquery ajax objects inside an array so that I can manually cancel the call,if it has not returned, based on user triggered events. These are ajax calls that I expect to run long.

**JavaScript**

```
var ajaxCalls = [];
ajaxCalls[0] = $.ajax({...});

$("#cancelButton").on("click", function() { ajaxCalls[0].abort(); });
```

The problem that exists is that the jqXHR object disappears from the array after the abort() method is called.

Now this looks great when it comes to managing the memory of my objects as it is magically removing itself and cleaning up nicely. However, it leaves an anti-pattern in my code where it looks like I am not cleaning up after myself. It also defeats the purpose of me creating a remove companion method to my add method.

Is there a reason for this? If my array contains more then 1 object it re-sizes itself completely appropriately.

This array if the letters were jqXHR objects

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Becomes this array when jqXHR object 'b' completes

```
['a', 'c', 'd']
```

Reading the code, one would expect that this would occur

```
['a', null/undefined, 'c', 'd']
```

WHY?

**EDIT:**

Here is a fiddle that I was able to get to reproduce what I am doing.

As a direct array element:

```
[ jqXHR, jqXHR, jqXHR ]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/itanex/uHX8q/

As a Key Value object element in the array:

```
[ { key: "key", value: jqXHR }, { key: "key", value: jqXHR } ]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/itanex/7DSrg/

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I'm not seeing that behavior here: http://jsfiddle.net/KXjam/.

Comment: I've done this several times in different projects, and never had that issue. I've also tested it every way I can think  of the last 15 minutes here -> http://jsfiddle.net/6Rq7J/ and can not reproduce that issue at all, the XHR object is always available after an abort, and is never removed from the array automagically ?

Comment: I have had a hard time trying to get an example of this without setting up a service to call that purposefully has a long duration to be able to appropriately demonstrate this.

Comment: jsFiddle has that built in, just see the above Fiddle in my previous comment ?

Comment: OK I see that now. Learned something new about jsfiddle. Let me see if I can reproduce everything as an example now.

Comment: It does not make sense since by looking at the code above, xhr object has no reference to array at all. It is impossible for it to remove itself from container array. You must give us more context code before and after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `complete` callback runs when you abort the call. So this happens:

```
ajaxCalls.pop();
```

And there goes your jqXHR object.

Added a `console.log` to show the `pop`:

http://jsfiddle.net/ycpZc/

Comment: So I am just getting tangled into the 'Great Weave' that I made. Guess it is a combination of the weekend and a clear view on the code that shows that with all the async behaviors happening, my object was being cleaned up as I had set up.